# After navigating to each link in the webpage,how to get list of all forms with method =post using selenium java

Tags: java, html, forms, selenium

How to continue after navigation to each url

I am struck with steps,Grab html content of the page and reg expressions to find the forms

```
 List<WebElement> demovar=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[not(contains(.,'Log Out'))]"));
   System.out.println(demovar.size());

       ArrayList<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>(); //List for storing all href values for 'a' tag

          for (WebElement var : demovar) {
              System.out.println(var.getText()); // used to get text present between the anchor tags
              System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
              hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href")); 
              System.out.println("*************************************");
          }

          //Navigating to each link
          int i=0;
          for (String href : hrefs) {
              driver.navigate().to(href);

              System.out.println((++i)+": navigated to URL with href: "+href);
              Thread.sleep(5000); // To check if the navigation is happening properly.
              System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

              // Grab HTML Content of the page 
           String content = getHtmlContent();


              // Reg.expression finds forms
            //  List<String> listOfForm = getAllPostMethodForms();
```

Comment: You should be able to grab the content without navigating to the page ( hrefs). There are variety of open source tools /jars available to do that exactly.

Comment: @Sureshmani its not mandatory that i have to navigate.

Comment: I need to get all form info with method =post from all the links in the application

Comment: xpath = //form[@method="post"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), there are way better [locator strategies](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) which can talk to [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) as it's a structured information.

For example you can go for [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727):

- `//form` - will return all the [`<forms>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) in the page
- `//form[@method='post']` - will return only the ones having [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) method

  ```
  List<WebElement> forms driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@method='post']"));
  ```

Comment: I tried.But how do i print the html data on console?

Comment: `System.out.println(form.getAttribute("innerHtml"));`